# t.map is not a function error on react static server

Tags: reactjs, static

I used npm build to build my react project and then copied the build to the server folder. When I check it with static server I got the following error:

```
TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at W (cardsRender.jsx:9)
```

The relevent code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './card';

const CardRender = ({cards,favs,onHandleFavs}) => {
    return (         
        <div className="row">
            {cards?.length > 0 &&
            cards.map((card) =>
            <Card key={card._id}
                  card={card} 
                  favs={favs} 
                  onHandleFavs={ () => onHandleFavs(card._id)}
                />)}
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default CardRender;
```

Comment: log the value of `cards` inside the `CardRender` and include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

it literally means  `t` is not iterate meaning not an array . make sure that is an array first